# Adding edge weights from dataframe with igraph in R

Tags: r, igraph

I created a graph object

```
ig <- graph(df$ig)
```

And would like to be able to plot the graph with weighted edges according to the network matrix

```
ig[]
```

The `ig[]` is not weighted, how do I add the weights directly from the network matrix so I can access it with `E(ig)$weight`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answer may help ([[igraph] capturing edge weights in g <- graph.data.frame?](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/igraph-help/2013-02/msg00079.html)):

If the weights are not given in the data frame explicitly but you simply want 
to use the number of email exchanges as weights, you can do this:

```
> df <- data.frame(from=c("a", "b", "a"), to=c("b", "a", "b"))
> g <- graph.data.frame(df)
> E(g)$weight <- 1
> g <- simplify(g, edge.attr.comb="sum")
```

I have then added the following line to be able to plot the width in the graph.

```
 E(themes_graph)$width <-E(themes_graph)$weight/15
```

Answer (score 2):

You can weight to your graph like this:

Example:
`gg3 <- graph.ring(10)`

```
 [1,] . 1 . . . . . . . 1
 [2,] 1 . 1 . . . . . . .
 [3,] . 1 . 1 . . . . . .
 [4,] . . 1 . 1 . . . . .
 [5,] . . . 1 . 1 . . . .
 [6,] . . . . 1 . 1 . . .
 [7,] . . . . . 1 . 1 . .
 [8,] . . . . . . 1 . 1 .
 [9,] . . . . . . . 1 . 1
[10,] 1 . . . . . . . 1 .
```

> `E(gg3)$weight <- 15`

```
 [1,]  . 15  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 15
 [2,] 15  . 15  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
 [3,]  . 15  . 15  .  .  .  .  .  .
 [4,]  .  . 15  . 15  .  .  .  .  .
 [5,]  .  .  . 15  . 15  .  .  .  .
 [6,]  .  .  .  . 15  . 15  .  .  .
 [7,]  .  .  .  .  . 15  . 15  .  .
 [8,]  .  .  .  .  .  . 15  . 15  .
 [9,]  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 15  . 15
[10,] 15  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 15  .
```

or

> `E(gg3)$weight <- c(20,10)`

```
 [1,]  . 20  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 10
 [2,] 20  . 10  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
 [3,]  . 10  . 20  .  .  .  .  .  .
 [4,]  .  . 20  . 10  .  .  .  .  .
 [5,]  .  .  . 10  . 20  .  .  .  .
 [6,]  .  .  .  . 20  . 10  .  .  .
 [7,]  .  .  .  .  . 10  . 20  .  .
 [8,]  .  .  .  .  .  . 20  . 10  .
 [9,]  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 10  . 20
[10,] 10  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 20  .
```

Check this out:
[Using edge-lists with associated edge values to create a weighted network](http://www.shizukalab.com/toolkits/sna/weighted-edgelists).

Comment: What if you want to calculate the weights from the occurrences of the edges?